# Remove previous and next topic from html, sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to remove the `Next topic` and `Previous topic` from my html pages.

I have tried setting `prev_next_buttons_location` to `False` in `html_theme_options` of `conf.py` but I got a **WARNING** telling me that this option is not available for my current theme (which is *nature*).

Another way to remove them would be to not declare the other *rst* sources from the *index*'s table of contents (my first version of the document was with only `index.rst` and I did not have the `Next` and `Previous` buttons): I tried with the flag `:hidden:` of `.. toctree::` but I still have them. Removing `.. toctree::` is not a solution because I have **WARNINGS** for each files that are not declared.

Should I change my theme to another that supports `prev_next_buttons_location`? (I really do not want to change my theme)

Is there a way to remove the buttons from my generated pages?

Comment: You can override any of the theme's template files. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#jinja-sphinx-templating-primer

Comment: Thank you. Reading the documentation now and `sidebarrel` seems to be the element to remove. It seems that it still appears in the generated page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to express the problem is: how to not include some files into the toctree ?

First I tried to add the files in `exclude_patterns` but then they were not generated to html. I went back to the doc and read this

> Use exclude_patterns to explicitly exclude documents or directories
>   from building completely. Use the “orphan” metadata to let a document
>   be built, but notify Sphinx that it is not reachable via a toctree.

Then I followed the link about "orphan" metadata: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/field-lists.html#metadata

And this is the solution: just add `:orphan:` in the beginning of the file. As written in the doc:

> If set, warnings about this file not being included in any toctree
>   will be suppressed.

So, this solved the problem.